# Problem resuming after suspend

Tags: suspend

So, the computer suspends just fine. When I try to wake it up, the screen flickers a bit, and then there's a black screen with all kinds of awful colored lines all over it. The mouse works normally, but it seems to be the only thing that functions. The only way to fix it seems to be doing a hard power off.

My graphics card is Nvidia, but that's all I really know about it.

My computer is a HP Pavillion dv9000.

Comment: Did you try to install the nVidia drivers by opening a program called Additional Drivers and activating a driver? It's OK if you're unsure, but it is something that is only done by manual user request and can cause changes that can cause the issue you are having.

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ, thanks for your comment! That fixed my problems with suspending :)

Comment: @hexafraction Please, move your comment into an answer.

Comment: @Lucio [Done](http://askubuntu.com/a/369937/54298).

Answer (score 2):

You should install the nVidia drivers. A program or section of software center (depending on Ubuntu version) is available for your use. Within that utility, select and activate the nvidia driver(current is optimal but past versions can be selected if the current is broken for your setup). Authenticate if prompted to, and reboot when finished.

> <sub>Did you try to install the nVidia drivers by opening a program called Additional Drivers and activating a driver? It's OK if you're unsure, but it is something that is only done by manual user request and can cause changes that can cause the issue you are having.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Try experimenting the arguments of pm-suspend, for example, to get the command line options, run as root

`# pm-suspend --help`

Then try, for example,

`# pm-suspend --quirk-radeon-off`

If some quirk works for you, then all you have to do is to edit /usr/sbin/pm-suspend and set the variable PM_CMDLINE to PM_CMDLINE="--quirk-radeon-off $@" or whatever option works for you.